# Creating an PHP API with php fpm and Socket connection

Tags: php, sockets, fpm

i want to create a PHP API that can be used as a microservice. It should not be accessible from the internet, so connection security is not an issue. Priority is performance. I was thinking of using a simple TCP socket connection to get rid of HTTP overhead and to have a persistent connection. But I also want to use the strengths of php-fpm. 
Is something like this possible?

```
+---------------------+   +-----------+   +--------------------+
| php App (stateless) +---+  php-fpm  +---+ tcp socket server? |
+---------------------+   +-----------+   +--------------------+
```

could I use nginx as the tcp server? or could i directly connect with php-fpm?

I hope my intention is clear. Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for everyone trying to build microservices including state full services that can use persistent socket connections and would also like to use PHP, this is how I did it.

- I created a node server, binding a TCP socket.
- The server also connects to php-fpm (i used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phpfpm thank you for the library)

I used json to communicate with the server that acts as a bridge to the php app.